# Understanding Android Fingerprint API authenticate() in depth

Tags: android, encryption, handler, fingerprint

I'm working on Android FingerPrint native API's for couple of days and there are two things that I'm confused with. The documentation has the examples but doesn't explain **why** we need to work this way, so please, any security Guru here?

I want to understand in depth the `authenticate()` function of the API's, or to be more specific to understand two of the parameters it takes : `CryptoObject` and `Handler`. It is working "*perfect*" at my POV when passing `null` to both of these parameters. So there is actually two questions:
Why we need to use CryptoObject and/or Handler while calling to authenticate (under what circumstances we want to encode and use not main handler)? Maybe some examples (even not code - but use cases). Thanks in advance. Love this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**CryptoObject** let you sign data. Keys to sign data are stored on secure hardware (Secure Element) on device. Data is signed by this Secure Element. Secure Element can only sign data when Fingerprint is recognized. Keys never go outside Secure Element.
Please read this http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2015/10/new-in-android-samples-authenticating.html

If you just want to authenticate a user `CrytoObject` is unnecessary. If you want encrypt or decrypt data with a key stored in secure storage (secure element in hardware) then you could use `CryptoObject`. This secured key is available to crypt or decrypt data only after an authentication.

**Handler** You can optionally provide a `Handler`. If provided, `FingerprintManager` will use the Looper from this `Handler` for its inner MyHandler instance.

```
private void useHandler(Handler handler) { 
    if (handler != null) { 
        mHandler = new MyHandler(handler.getLooper()); 
    } else if  (mHandler.getLooper() != mContext.getMainLooper()) { 
        mHandler = new MyHandler(mContext.getMainLooper()); 
    } 
}
```

Providing the looper allows us to define what thread to run on and listen for message logging.

```
Looper looper = Looper.getMainLooper(); 
looper.setMessageLogging(new Printer() { 
    @Override 
    public void println(String x) { 
        Log.d(TAG, x); 
    } 
}); 
mFingerprintManager.authenticate(cryptoObject, mCancellationSignal, 0, this, new Handler(looper));
```

Please read this https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/introducing-androids-fingerprint-api

Comment: Not sure if I still understand the usage of the `CryptoObject`. Why isn't it enough for the OS to recognize a users fingerprint to unlock some data or feature? Why is this extra layer of security available and why would I prefer to use it over simply passing in null? @laurenty, can you elaborate on this?